# Is React Native free to use?

Tags: react-native

I am currently developing an iOS app in swift for a year, I still confused about the pricing difference of React Native and Xcode because as far I know Xcode is free to use, but I am going to become an Hybrid developer, so is there any fees that I need to pay for React Native?

Comment: There is no fee to use React Native. It has a MIT License. See [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/LICENSE)

Comment: You have to pay 100$ a year for your apple developer account and 25$ (lifetime) google play dev account.

Comment: Do we need to pay for react native while publishing like Ionic @AntoineGrandchamp

Comment: @subashchandru No you don't

Answer (score 3):

As found in the [React Native license doc](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/LICENSE):

> Permission is hereby granted, **free of charge**, to any person obtaining a copy
>   of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
>   in the Software without restriction...

<sup>*Emphasis mine*</sup>

In short words: React Native is free to use and you will never have to pay for it.